Format timestamp in php from date to time in fractions
I apologise in advance because this question was most likely asked before, but I can't find it because I am not sure what phrase to use.
I have a date timestamp in php from Unix Epoch format. The results I have are summed and output in format hh:ss.
What I need is, to display total time in hours and "fractions" of hours.
For example:
36:15 hrs needs to be 36.25
36:30 hrs need to be 36.5
36:45 hrs need to be 36.75
What is best way to convert this?
Many thanks

Your time tormat in the output is hh:mm not hh:ss. I would extract the minutes and then divide 60 by minutes. Attach the result to the hours.
